# Uniform Method for the Calculation to Probabilities and Expectations Limited by Inequalities

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value

Given a group of inqualities that can limit every unknowns in a finite range, and every unknowns are in uniform distrubtion. Is there a **universal** way to calculate the probabilities of another inequality or the expectations of one of the unknowns?

For example, $x$ and $y$ are unknowns that satisfy the following inqualities:
$$
0<x<\frac23\\
0<y<1-x.
$$
By looking at the image we can know $P(x<y)=\frac9{16}$, and $E(y)=\frac13$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $P[A|B]=P[A\text{ and } B]/P[B]$.
If $X$ and $Y$ are uniform on the interval $[0,1]$, then
$$P[X<Y|0<X<\frac{2}3,0<Y<1-X]
=\frac{\int_0^{\frac{2}3}\int_{\max\{0,x\}}^{1-x}1dydx}{\int_0^{\frac{2}3}\int_{0}^{1-x}1dydx}
=\frac{1}2$$
and
$$E[Y|0<X<\frac{2}3,0<Y<1-X]
=\frac{\int_0^{\frac{2}3}\int_{0}^{1-x}ydydx}{\int_0^{\frac{2}3}\int_{0}^{1-x}1dydx}
=\frac{13}{16}$$